# Saving Carbon from string to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm having trouble saving a timestamp to my MySQL database. In this case, the user writes a date in a text field, with the format dd/mm/yyyy, and I want it to be saved as a timestamp.

The problem is, it is always complaining about incorrect format.

So far, I've tried:

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i:s", $request['b_date'] . " 00:00:00");

// or
$d = Carbon::parse($request['b_date']);

// or

$d = Carbon::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i:s", $request['b_date'] . " 00:00:00");

// so that I can
$p->b_date = $d;
```

But it never lets me save it.
Here's the log:

```
[2019-05-29 15:14:02] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1111-11-11 00:00:00' for column 'b_date' at row 1 ...
```

I've been trying to do this for hours. What am I missing?

And how can '1111-11-11 00:00:00' be an invalid datetime value?

Comment: Is it a `timestamp` datatype? `TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.` The `Datetime` has a larger range, `1000` - `9999`. -https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: It is! Thank you very much! Your hint solved my problem. It works now.

Comment: @LuísHenriques please, provide your solution as an answer of your own question so this could help other people with your same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring the datatype as DateTime in the migrations script worked for me.

```
    ...

    Schema::create(...

        $table->dateTime('b_date'); // use dateTime instead of timestamp

        ...
```

Setting it with carbon in the controller:

```
...

$p->b_date = Carbon::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i:s", $input['b_date'] . " 00:00:00");

...
```